# What is wrong with this objective-c statement

Tags: objective-c

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SingleWord.sqlite"]];
```

XCode says "expect ';' after expression"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Maybe the error is a few lines up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get even 4 errors in this string:

1)receiver type 'ViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'applicationDocumentsDirectory' [4]

2)Parse Issue: Expected ';' at end of declaration

3)Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression

4)Parse Issue: Expected expression

So I think your problem is you haven't a method or variable "applicationDocumentsDirectory"

Comment: I forgot to add method applicationDocumentsDirectory. Everything is fine after the method was added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hey problem is not in this statement , it may be some where other . you may be forget ; somewhere other place or may be you forget to add bracket in one of your method.